# Angular filter works, but sees input as undefined and throws error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I wrote a filter that appears to be working fine, although I am getting the following error.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceAll' of undefined`

The filter replaces erroneous relative urls with absolute ones. Here is the filter and markup.

```
//located elsewhere
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(s,r){
    return this.split(s).join(r);
}
//located elsewhere
var imgBase = '<img src="http://discourse.mysite.com';

app.filter('prependImg_topic', function(){
  return function(cooked) {
    return cooked.replaceAll('<img src="//discourse.mysite.com', imgBase);
  }
})
```

Markup:

```
<div class="topic-post-body" ng-bind-html="topic.post_stream.posts[0].cooked | prependImg_topic "></div> "
```

I have an inclination that I need to use `$sce` because I am inputting the data in `ng-bind-html`. If I print the value like so: `{{topic.post_stream.posts[0].cooked}}` , it exists, so I know it is not undefined. In addition, the filter works and properly writes urls. Go figure.

I can provide any additional details needed to help answer. Thanks.

EDIT: Another oddity that may help is that inside of a `ng-repeat` this filter works, and throws no errors. Trippy stuff!

```
<div class="post" ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-if="$index > 0">
     <div class="topic-post-body" ng-bind-html="post.cooked | prependImg_topic"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the data is loaded asynchronously, if that's the case it is no wonder the filter throws an errors since it is trying to operate on (yet) non-existent data. The check you make `{{ topic ... }}` doesn't prove anything because it will print the data if that data will eventually come (better check with `console.log`). The reason why the filter inside `ng-repeat` doesn't throw any errors is because the `ng-repeat` will only work if there is any data to iterate on, that means that when the filter inside `ng-repeat` runs the data is already there.
That's also the reason why you should always construct filters in such a way that they can handle `undefined` or `null` values without throwing.

Comment: They are loaded asynchronously, but via promises from services, and If it is available to the view, it will also be available to the filter AFAIK. I actually think its a race condition where the internal `ng-bind-html` directive is taking a bit of time to parse the html, thus the filter not having access to it. ps i didnt downvote you, thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, that's true, it **will** be available, that means that at the moment the value of `topic.post_stream.posts[0].cooked` is `undefined`, but that doesn't stop the filter from operating on that value. And since the value is  `undefined` **atm** the filter throws an error because `undefined` doesn't have a method `replaceAll` as stated by the error message.

Comment: The reason why the check you make with `{{ ... }}` doesn't throw is because $interpolate service knows how to handle `undefined` values.

Comment: Interesting idea. The fact that it is working makes me strongly think the DOM has access to that data at filtration time. Really appreciate your responses.

Comment: You were right. apparently filters get run very early, and ofter. Need to check for value existence. Thanks.

Comment: Every angular expression which you put in template is reevaluated on every  digest, since filters are usually used in such a expressions, they get executed too. That's why they run very often, because digests run very often.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Cheers

Comment: I put a check in my filter see if my input was undefined and that fixed the error for me. However I felt like there should be an easier fix. What I found is that if you initialize your objects first while waiting on your promise to complete that fixes the problem. Just setting my object like $scope.object = []; fixes the problem.